# How can I pass a parameter in an sql query without making it explicit in the query itself?

Tags: java, sql, ignite

I'm testing my ignite cache, inserting a simple User in the cache and then through a query I get the User entered previously returned I have a problem writing the query. I noticed that writing like this:

```
@Test
    @EnableStreamCacheTestUtil(caches = {@Cache(name = "User", queryEntity = {@QueryEntity(tableName = "USER", keyClass = String.class, valueClass = User.class)})})
    public void Test_expected_Ok() throws Exception {
        Ignite ignite = Ignition.ignite();


        UsersRequest usersRequest = new UsersRequest();
        usersRequest.setName(TestCostants.NAME);
   

        IgniteCache<String, User> igniteCache = ignite.cache("User");
        User user = new User("Ennio","Ragno",90")
        igniteCache.put("1", user);
    

        SqlFieldsQuery sql = new SqlFieldsQuery("SELECT * " +
                " FROM USER WHERE NAME ='ENNIO'");

        int counter = 0;
        List<List<?>> cursor = igniteCache.query(sql).getAll();
        // try(QueryCursor<List<?>> cursor = igniteCache.query(sql)) {
        for (List<?> row : cursor) {
            log.info("SQLQUeryresult:{}", row);
            counter++;
        }
        Assertions.assertEquals(1,counter);
      }

    
    }
```

The test works fine, but if I write the query like this

```
        //Clearly in the constant that there is the value "ENNIO"
        UsersRequest usersRequest = new UsersRequest();
        usersRequest.setName(TestCostants.NAME);

        //some code

       
        SqlFieldsQuery sql = new SqlFieldsQuery("SELECT * " +
                " FROM USER WHERE NAME = "+usersRequest.getName());
```

Now it doesn't work anymore. This is my first time trying to use queries and caches, but technically, shouldn't it be the same?Is there a different way to write the query when passing parameters like this?

Comment: First - You are missing a ')' after the ...usersRequest.getName(). Second, can you try this `"SELECT * FROM USER WHERE NAME = '"+usersRequest.getName()+"'" ` This encloses the usersRequest.getName() in single quotes and appends it to the end of query.

Comment: Hi @AdilKhalil, you're right, probably while copying the text I deleted it! iI'll try your solution right away, I'll let you know right away

Comment: @AdilKhalil Concatenating values into a query string makes it vulnerable to SQL injection. Suggestions to persist in such insecure practices are not a good idea.

Comment: @AdilKhalil You're wrong, guess what happens if `something` has the value `' OR ''='`, you now have a condition `where name = '' OR ''=''`, which is always true, and that is only a relatively benign form of SQL injection, worse things can be done this way. Just putting quotes around it doesn't remove the SQL injection risk associated with concatenation. You either need to properly escape values, or - better - use parameters.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I stand corrected. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way is to use parameter substitution, avoid SQL injection and other troubles:

```
    //Clearly in the constant that there is the value "ENNIO"
    UsersRequest usersRequest = new UsersRequest();
    usersRequest.setName(TestCostants.NAME);

    //some code

   
    SqlFieldsQuery sql = new SqlFieldsQuery("SELECT * " +
            " FROM USER WHERE NAME = ?").setArgs(usersRequest.getName());
```

Answer (score 2):

In your between code you set a value in cache which later is retrieved with `.getName()`

```
        IgniteCache<String, User> igniteCache = ignite.cache("User");
        User user = new User("Ennio","Ragno",90")
        igniteCache.put("1", user);
```

Ennio is different from ENNIO

```
SqlFieldsQuery sql = new SqlFieldsQuery("SELECT * " +
                " FROM USER WHERE NAME ='ENNIO'");
```

And your cache probably returns ennio for userName when you invoke `usersRequest.getName()`

So the difference between

```
 SqlFieldsQuery sql = new SqlFieldsQuery("SELECT * " +
                " FROM USER WHERE NAME ='ENNIO'");
```

which is successful and the second one

```
SqlFieldsQuery sql = new SqlFieldsQuery("SELECT * " +
                " FROM USER WHERE NAME = "+usersRequest.getName());
```

which fails is that the second one is called with `Ennio` instead of `ENNIO`